# how to sync p4 from a backup of a workspace

Tags: perforce

I've got a very large depot synced to my workstation, I'm trying to get a few more computers up to date without requiring them to sync as well. We've copied over all the files from my computer into their working directories and are trying to get perforce to recognize that they already have these files at a specific revision.

It sounds like `flush` is what we're looking for, but it doesn't seem to be working. What I'm trying is:

`p4 flush //ourdepotname/...#123456`

However nothing changes. If I add:

`p4 flush -f //ourdepotname/...#123456`

then I'll see all my files are recognized as version 0/x in p4v now.

Is flush not what we need? How can we get P4 to recognize that we already have all the files locally at revision `123456`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was indicating a revision when I meant to indicate a change list.

`p4 flush //ourdepotname/...@123456`

---

Thanks to Sam Stafford for clarification.

Comment: #n is for a revision number (scoped to an individual file), @n is for a changelist number (global across the repository).